# How can I update these initialized "imported" buttons?

Tags: python, tkinter, properties

I'm using this class called Combobox_Autocomplete from here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/580770-combobox-autocomplete/

It essentially creates an Entry, with an autocomplete feature, based on a list given to it when the class is instantiated.

In my case, to simplify, let's say I have to columns in my table, which looks like:

```
Car_model | Color
    1     | Red
    1     | Blue
    1     | Green
    2     | Red
    2     | Blue
    3     | Red
    3     | Yellow
```

What I essentially want, is two of these Auto complete boxes, the first one with the car model, the second one is the color, which gets adjusted depending on which car is selected.

I'm running into a roadblock when it comes to updating the second list in the second autocomplete block. Here is what my code looks like:

```
class maconomy:
    def __init__(self,master):
        # Assuming df2 is my table
        # Create unique lists of both columns for the autofill features
        self.mylist = list(set(self.df2['Car_model'].tolist()))
        self.myList2 = list(set(self.df2['Color'].tolist()))

        self.combobox_autocomplete1 = Combobox_Autocomplete(master, 
        self.mylist, highlightthickness=1)
        self.combobox_autocomplete1.grid(row = 1, column = 1,padx=10, pady=10)
        self.combobox_autocomplete1.bind('<Double-Return>', lambda event, 
        arg=1: self.update(event, arg))

        self.combobox_autocomplete2 = Combobox_Autocomplete(master, 
        self.myList2, highlightthickness=1)
        self.combobox_autocomplete2.grid(row = 2, column = 1,padx=10, pady=10)
        self.combobox_autocomplete2.bind('<Double-Return>', lambda event, 
        arg=2: self.update(event, arg)) 

    # Update method just switches to next combobox 
    def update(self,event,arg):
        if arg == 5:
            self.commitButton.focus_set()
        else:
            eval('self.combobox_autocomplete'+str(arg+1)+'.focus_set()')
```

My main idea was to make the mylist2 a property. Update it, depending on what the car_model is. this is what i had:

```
    @property
    def mylist2(self):
        if self.combobox_autocomplete1.get_value() != "":
            self.myList2 = df2[df2['Car_model'] ==self.combobox_autocomplete1.get_value()]['Color']
            return myList2
        else:
            return myList2
```

This does not however update the list associated to the combobox, seeing as it does not re initialize the combobox. Does anyone have any idea of how I could achieve this?

Comment: How do i go about re creating it?

I could try making it a property, but does that mean i have to replace it on the grid?

Comment: Use `.combobox_autocomplete2.list_of_items = myList2`